# How to display bootstrap slider image full screen without stretching on mobile device using img tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I founded slider on this link (http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/rrVPZd). It's working for me on desktop but getting issue on mobile device.This slider is not display full screen on mobile.I tried below css and getting full screen but image is stretching.I have to display only center part of image.I am using img tag.Would you help me in this.

Thanks in advance

**Css**

//getting image full screen in mobile device.

```
 .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img{
  height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected your code a bit.
The main idea is to use backgrounds instead of imgs to achieve cover effect.
Here my fork http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/mArjzB 
Here are corrections:
1. Changes from imgs to backgrounds

```
.carousel-inner .item {
/*   max-height: 680px; */
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4357218/Assets/Images/Codepen/Bootstrap%20Carousel/slide-1.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4357218/Assets/Images/Codepen/Bootstrap%20Carousel/slide-2.jpg');
}

.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4357218/Assets/Images/Codepen/Bootstrap%20Carousel/slide-3.jpg');
}
```

2. To center the title vertically on small screens

```
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 36%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-caption {
    right: 20%;
    left: 20%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Mr.g1un..Its working perfectly for me.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1600/600" /></a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Meow</h3>
        <p>Just Kitten Around</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Use this it won't stretching on mobile

Comment: Mr.Shahzaib..Whats difference in your code and that code?..Please help me in this?

Comment: i mostly use this code, it won't stretching on mobile just try this and check

Comment: Mr.Shahzaib i checked you code but it not displaying full screen.I checked on http://www.responsinator.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
}
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
    background: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417021423914-070979c8eb34?q=75&fm=jpg&s=55746bd56e02a131b1e48c12196ea866) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/reserve/oY3ayprWQlewtG7N4OXl_DSC_5225-2.jpg?q=75&fm=jpg&s=85ab821f3fa535036a68155aab571bad) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1414073875831-b47709631146?q=75&fm=jpg&s=731b6d5150eea8bafa63ae8194e72ebd) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.carousel {
    z-index: -99;
}
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```
<div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="title">
  <h1>This is Awesome</h1>
</div>
```